# Do hostiles have advantage when attacking friendly affected by self-casted faerie fire?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, area-of-effect

I have a rather simple question. Suppose I cast faerie fire and a friendly is in the target cube at that time and thus affected, do hostiles have advantage when attacking it?

I believe the PHB's spell description does imply this:

> Any attack roll against an affected creature or object has advantage if the attacker can see it, and the affected creature or object can’t benefit from being invisible.

But it surprises me as this implies I need to be seriously careful having faerie fire affect fellow party members?